# Not required field url in banners kentico 9

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

How to make a not required url field in banners or it is impossible?
Kentico 9

Answer (score 0):

The easy part is adding the field.  The hard part is modifying the code files to accommodate that new field. The Banner management module is sealed so you'd need to unseal that module via a database query and add the field to the Banners class in the "Banner management" module.

```
select ClassResourceID, *
from cms_class
where classname = 'cms.banner'

select *
from cms_resource 
where resourceid = 271 -- resource id from above query

update cms_resource
set ShowInDevelopment = 1
where resourceid = 271 -- resource id from first query
```

Clear your cache and reload the modules and you should be able to add a field to the Banner module class.

Next, you will need to go through the code files, which you can find in the `/CMSModules/BannerManagement` directory, and make modifications where needed so that new field is accessible on your forms and other places.

Lastly, you will have to review any web parts and update them as well with the new field (if needed).

DISCLAIMER - Modifying base Kentico code files is not recommended or supported at all.